# Creating a method for an abstract class in java

Tags: java, generics, methods, abstract-class

I am trying to create a method for an abstract class in Java.

Say B and C extend abstract A.

Within A there is a method `void doSomething(???)`

I want `B.doSomething(B)` to work, but `B.doSomething(C)` should not.  I also want `C.doSomething(C)` to work, but `C.doSomething(B)` should not. Is this possible?

EDIT: I want the method to be defined in A

EDIT 2: Using LaShane's answer...

```
A b = new B();
A c = new C();
b.doSomething(c);//how can I prevent this?
```

Comment: 1) B should be able to take only other B's in as an argument, 2) B and C are just classes that extends abstract A, 3) Generics because I want A to define a method that generically handles this situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement it in this way:

```
abstract class A<T> {
    abstract void doSomething(T obj);
};

class B extends A<B> {

    @Override
    void doSomething(B obj) {
    }

};

class C extends A<C> {

    @Override
    void doSomething(C obj) {
    }

};
```

Comment: @DaiwikDaarun you cannot prevent it fully, but `((A)b).doSomething(c);` will emit warning and you can compile with `-Werror` to treat warnings as errors

Comment: @Sigismundus C extends A, not B

Comment: OK, that's even better